# wordpress htaccess url rewritting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to create some rewriting rules in the htaccess file for my website designed with wordpress.

I have tried to insert the following lines of code in the htaccess file to simply test whether I could create a very simple redirection from www.mywebsite.com/hello to www.mywebsite.com/index.php :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/hello$
RewriteRule ^/hello$  /index.php [L]
```

I have added these rows just before the end of the  IfModule mod_rewrite.c (ie after all the RewriteCond ... RewriteRule that were already written by wordpress).

```
</IfModule>
# END WPSuperCache
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong ? Is my syntax incorrect ? Am I inserting the rule at the wrong place ?

Thank you,

Comment: 1. You don’t need to check the same thing twice, using two different methods - remove the RewriteCond, it serves little purpose here. 2. When configured in .htaccess context, the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: 3. _“(ie after all the RewriteCond ... RewriteRule that were already written by wordpress)”_ - if `/hello` does not match onto a physically existing file or folder, then you need to do this stuff _before_ the WP rewrites, otherwise the WP rewriting will have rewritten this to the index.php internally at this point already.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I removed the RewriteCond and the slash. I tried to put it before the WP rewrites but unfortunatelly that did not work. 
This is what I do :
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteRule ^hello$  /index.php [L]
...blablabla wordpress stuff
</IfModule>
# END WPSuperCache

What do you think is wrong with that ?

Comment: When you rewrite stuff to the index.php of WordPress, it will still try and use the original URL, to find any content by that slug. You would have to make this an external direct, if you want this to automatically show your WP start page.

Comment: Hello,
thanks, I think it works! However, when I try to rewrite an address with parameters, I don't understand why but although I write in the url bar the pretty address (rewritten) it converts it and the parameters become visible. It gives me the impression of a redirection, yet I wrote RewriteRule well. Do you know why ? Thanks again for your help.